# Error al ejecutar Rails g, ya sea con controller o model o cualquier otro

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Al ejecutar Rails g me manda esto:

> In addition to those commands, there are:
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in `require': cannot load such file -- puppet (LoadError)     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`block in require'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:259:in `load_dependency'  from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293:in`require'  from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/scaffold-0.0.3/lib/scaffold.rb:5:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in`
>   require'     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in
>   `block (2 levels) in require'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in`each'     from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
>     from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in`each'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'  from
>   /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:106:in`require'     from
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Dropbox/Tegnolabs/config/application.rb:7:in `<top
>   (required)>'  from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in`
>   require'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:156:in
>   `require_application_and_environment!'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:24:in`
>   block in rake_tasks'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/reporting.rb:36:in
>   `silence'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/deprecation/instance_delegator.rb:20:in`
>   silence'     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:23:in
>   `rake_tasks'  from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/rake_proxy.rb:34:in`
>   formatted_rake_tasks'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:122:in
>   `help'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in`
>   run_command!'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.2/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Dropbox/Tegnolabs/bin/rails:9:in`require'  from
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/Dropbox/Tegnolabs/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>     from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`
>   load'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in
>   `call'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`
>   call'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
>     from /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/bin/spring:49:in`'  from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in
>   `load'    from
>   /var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/spring-2.0.1/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`
>   '    from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in
>   `require'     from
>   /usr/local/lib/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:68:in`
>   require'     from /opt/lampp/htdocs/Dropbox/Tegnolabs/bin/spring:15:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:3:in`load'  from bin/rails:3:in
>   `'

Comment: Puedes dar un poco mas de detalles? el log te dice que no puede cargar puppet, tienes instalado puppet?

Comment: amigo soy nuevo pero donde miro si tengo instalado puppet?

Comment: Como creaste la aplicación? si ejecutas `rails s` que te dice? puedes dar detalles de como llegaste a ese error, los pasos que seguiste

Comment: cada ves que ejecutaba bundle install me salia un msj que decía que ejecutara gem pristine --all
 lo ejecute y luego me salia eso

Comment: después de crear la aplicación con `rails new` hacer `bundle install` y ejecutar `gem pristine --all` le sale ese error? agrego alguna gema al fichero `Gemfile` ? tienes instalada la versión de ruby que viene en los repositorios?

Comment: utilizo debian y creo que es la 2.3.3  no se si esa sera la que viene en las repositorios, amigo ademas borre todo el gemfile y luego ejecute y volvió todo a la normalidad, pero luego instale scaffold y trate de utilizar el generador de scaffold y de ahí me sale ese error, que ademas ya no me deja ejecuta mas nada

Comment: Ok, creo que lo mejor es que empieces otra vez, primero elimina ruby y todo lo demás, luego instalalo ya sea con [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) o [rvm](https://rvm.io/) el que tu prefieras y vuelves a crear el proyecto